# Best way to prevent/warn IE <8 visitors

Tags: vb.net, internet-explorer, compatibility

We are running a vb.net webforms website. I need to implement a solution to either prevent or warn IE users with a version below 8. Im looking into possible solutions for this. Ive looked at modernizr, but that only looks at features, i want to simply block by IE version.

Also preferably i dont want to write my own user agent logic but use 'proven technology', as in a third party solution. Ideally it also takes into account wether or not IE is running in compatibility mode < IE8.

IM interested to hear what everyones take is on this and what the possible solutions are.

Comment: Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847580/how-to-detect-safari-chrome-ie-firefox-and-opera-browser you can redirect a user based on browser via JS

Comment: Unfortunately, this is a site for getting help with writing your own logic. Asking for recommendations for "proven technology" is off topic here.

Comment: In the end i ended up using bowser, but your link definately pointed me in the right direction. Thanks